# Copying c++ char pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this problem when copying values to a char pointer.
If I write

```
char* data = "abcdef";
char* d;

d[0] = data[0];
d[1] = data[1];
d[2] = data[2];
d[3] = data[3];
printf("%s ", d);
```

The output is `abcd`
but if  replace the last block with 
a this for loop which is basically the equivalent, it prints out nothing

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   d[i] = data[i];
}
```

Can anyone please explain what is the difference?

Comment: Since you have tagged this `C++`, you might want to start looking into `std::string`, `std::cout`, etc. Otherwise, this code is very `C`.

Answer (score 9):

Both programs have [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since you haven't allocated memory for `d`. They are free to behave in any way they please, including in the way you describe.

To fix this:

1. allocate memory for `d`;
2. make sure you write a NUL terminator to `d`.

P.S. The way you assign a string literal to a non-`const` variable is no longer valid in C++. Use

```
const char* data = "...";
^^^^^
```

P.P.S. Since you've tagged the question `[c++]`, you should probably be using `std::string` instead of raw C strings.

Comment: And for almost certainly going out-of-bounds on the `printf()` call even if memory had been allocated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But i've seen an example similar to this. char* c = "string one"; c = "another string"; So i thought it allocates memory on the go, with char pointers

Comment: @user2936347: Similar != identical. Details matter.

Comment: @user2936347 "similar"?

Comment: The dodgy conversion *was* deprecated. Since 2011, it isn't allowed at all.